# Adding a line of text underneath underneath a horizontal scroll of images with CSS

Tags: css, text, horizontal-scrolling

I am trying to put a line of text underneath the first image in an horizontal scroll. However, each time I try, it inserts the text mid way down the page and doesn't line up with the image.

I have attached my code below. Would someone be able to help and let me know the best way to achieve the above.

*Edit* Please find an image attached of what I am trying to achieve. [image]

Thank you in advance. Esmé

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: inherit;
}

.horizontal_slider {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #fff;
  line-height: 25em;
}

.horizontal_slider_video {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #fff;
  line-height: 25em;
}

.horizontal_slider::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}


/* for ms*/

.horizontal_slider {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}

.slider_container {
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.item {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.item img {
  width: px;
  height: 850px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider_container">
<div class="horizontal_slider">
  <div class="slider_container">
    <div style="text-align: left">
      <h2>Side by side sisters</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://freight.cargo.site/t/original/i/0b6e5d416b8d2666e95ad95076f5a051e7c744345a0c66f43667f08f1a2619d6/0007-copy.jpg">

    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://freight.cargo.site/t/original/i/21fae0988d8a0ae94a7dabcf10286fd8fc6e0488a3801de8017c2932024f46bb/0008-copy.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://freight.cargo.site/t/original/i/d045fce91bf44d863d7e5221f7ec9b61dbfe8d74145cb65120cbf7302f0ebbab/0006.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://freight.cargo.site/t/original/i/d045fce91bf44d863d7e5221f7ec9b61dbfe8d74145cb65120cbf7302f0ebbab/0006.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://freight.cargo.site/t/original/i/d045fce91bf44d863d7e5221f7ec9b61dbfe8d74145cb65120cbf7302f0ebbab/0006.jpg">
    </div>

    <img src="https://freight.cargo.site/t/original/i/d045fce91bf44d863d7e5221f7ec9b61dbfe8d74145cb65120cbf7302f0ebbab/0006.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show where you'd like the text to be/look like?

Answer (score 1):

The semantically correct way to do this is to wrap each image in a figure element and include a figcaption for the text. So something like:

```
<figure>
<img src="image.jpg" alt="image descriptor">
<figcaption>The caption that goes below the image</figcaption>
</figure>
```

You will no doubt need to adjust the css to make this look correct.